# HTTP requests from browsers stop working randomly (windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, browser, http

For some reason I can't understand, sometime (every hour or so), for a short period of time (15 sec.) the HTTP requests done from the web browsers are not working.

If I do a ping, it works fine. All other connections other than port 80 or 8080 are working properly. Since the issue is not constant, it's difficult to debug.

I've looked many different posts and haven't found anything yet that would fix this issue. Since it's my gaming PC, I almost have nothing installed on it (just the default windows firewall and antivirus). I've tried to disable many different services or kill processes without success.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What sites are you trying to reach? Maybe it's a problem with your ISP.

Comment: any random sites (from google, microsoft or any other web sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ping working it could be that you have DNS Issues.
try this :
open CMD
write `ipconfig /flushdns`

this will clean you dns List inside the computer.

Comment: I wasn't sure it would change something but while doing the cmd and getting an error, I found out that the DNS Client service was disabled. I'll see if it change something now.

Comment: Marked as answered for now since the problem hasn't occured since yesterday. Found some info for those having the same issue as me: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919746